# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: for using jsp mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

i am new to jsp and Mongodb I have to search data from mongodb based on my input in search field using jsp

here is my code

NewFIle.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#d0d0d0">
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<h2><center>enter Hospital details</center></h2>
<form name="searchhospital"action="searchhospital.jsp"method="post">
<table border="2"align=center>
<tr><td>
<b>enter the id u want tho search:</b>
<input type="text"name="id"/>
<br/>
<br/>
</td></tr>
</table>
<center>
<input type="submit"value="submit"/>
<input type="reset"value="reset"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

and search file as 
searchhospital.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.MongoClient"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.MongoException"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.WriteConcern"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DB"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DBCollection"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.BasicDBObject"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DBObject"%>
<%@page import="com.mongodb.DBCursor"%>
<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>id</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>branch</th>
</tr>

<%
try{    

    // To connect to mongodb server
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

    // Now connect to your databases
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "HealthCare" );
   System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
//    boolean auth = db.authenticate("","");
//    System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);

   DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("DocInfoTable");
    System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");

   BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
    String s2=request.getParameter("id");

    query.put("DocLastname",s2 );

    // Assign 1 or 0 for projecting a specific field.
    fields.put("_id", 0);
    fields.put("DOcFirstName", 1);
    fields.put("DOcFirstName", 1);
    fields.put("DocMiddleName", 1);
    fields.put("DocQualification", 1);

    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,fields);
    int i = 1;

    while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
         System.out.println(cursor.next()); 
    %>


    <tr>
<td><%=query.getString("DOcFirstName")%></td>
<td><%=query.getString("DOcFirstName")%></td>
<td><%=query.getString("DocMiddleName")%></td>
<td><%=query.getString("DocQualification")%></td>
</tr>
       <%

       i++;
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
 }
       %>




</body>
</html>
```

Iam getting error as follow

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: 

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.MongoClient resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.MongoException resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.WriteConcern resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.DB resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [19] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.DBCollection resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.BasicDBObject resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [21] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.DBObject resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [E:\all softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M9\work\Catalina\localhost\happy\org\apache\jsp\searchhospital_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.DBCursor resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
MongoClient cannot be resolved to a type
30: try{    
31:     
32:     // To connect to mongodb server
33:     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
34:         
35:     // Now connect to your databases
36:     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "HealthCare" );


An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
MongoClient cannot be resolved to a type
30: try{    
31:     
32:     // To connect to mongodb server
33:     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
34:         
35:     // Now connect to your databases
36:     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "HealthCare" );


An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
DB cannot be resolved to a type
33:     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
34:         
35:     // Now connect to your databases
36:     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "HealthCare" );
37:    System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
38: //    boolean auth = db.authenticate("","");
39: //    System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);


An error occurred at line: 41 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
DBCollection cannot be resolved to a type
38: //    boolean auth = db.authenticate("","");
39: //    System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
40:    
41:    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("DocInfoTable");
42:     System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");
43:         
44:    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();


An error occurred at line: 44 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
BasicDBObject cannot be resolved to a type
41:    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("DocInfoTable");
42:     System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");
43:         
44:    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
45:     BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
46:     String s2=request.getParameter("id");
47: 


An error occurred at line: 44 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
BasicDBObject cannot be resolved to a type
41:    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("DocInfoTable");
42:     System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");
43:         
44:    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
45:     BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
46:     String s2=request.getParameter("id");
47: 


An error occurred at line: 45 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
BasicDBObject cannot be resolved to a type
42:     System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");
43:         
44:    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
45:     BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
46:     String s2=request.getParameter("id");
47: 
48:     query.put("DocLastname",s2 );


An error occurred at line: 45 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
BasicDBObject cannot be resolved to a type
42:     System.out.println("Collection DocInfoTable selected successfully");
43:         
44:    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
45:     BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
46:     String s2=request.getParameter("id");
47: 
48:     query.put("DocLastname",s2 );


An error occurred at line: 57 in the jsp file: /searchhospital.jsp
DBCursor cannot be resolved to a type
54:     fields.put("DocMiddleName", 1);
55:     fields.put("DocQualification", 1);
56:    
57:     DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,fields);
58:     int i = 1;
59:         
60:     while (cursor.hasNext()) { 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9 logs.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
```

Please help me ragarding this issue.If my code is wrong than please provide good code to search data from Mongodb using jsp(or servlets)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your error message says, it can't import the mongodb classes.

`Only a type can be imported. com.mongodb.MongoClient resolves to a package`
Now, this doesn't *look* like a package name to me, but rather, a specific class in a package, so i doubt that error is quite right.

Is it possible your mongodb library isn't in the servlet container's libs folder or your application's libs folder?

Comment: Hello Zack , I have already  included Mongodb Jar files in                      java resourse->libraries(mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar) folder in  project , if i run normal java-mongodb connection program it i is working fine but i am not able to pull data to the front end by using jsp .Is this jar file enough or any other files do i need to add in project library ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoClient contains class within itself. Hence, importing MongoClient on jsp itself is not allowed.

What you need to do here is to submit the data to a servlet handling your request and take the code to the servlet. It is never a good practice to keep complete database connection code in the jsp.

I hope this helps. Let me know if further help is required

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. You need put "mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar" and "mongo-java-driver-3.5.0-javadoc.jar" into tomcat's lib. Also in you need put these two jar into lib which is under WEB-INF.